# How to generate xpath for this element to use in Selenium?

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
    <head>
    <body>
    <div id="page" class="container">
    <div id="header">
    <div id="mainmenu">
    <div class="breadcrumbs">
    <div class="container">
    <div id="content">
    <h1>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/dropdown/dropdown.css">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/dropdown/themes/default/default.css">
    <ul id="nav" class="dropdown dropdown-horizontal">
    <li class="dir">
    <li class="dir">
    <li class="dir">
    <font color="black">Retrieve</font>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <a href="/imsptools/index.php?r=SPPlite/default/retrieveWa1ir1s1service">wa1i-AFU R1S1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
```

I am using selenium to automate testing but got stuck in generating xpath of one auto drop down select element.

This is a auto drop down and select element in webpage. Can anyone help what should be xpath of  `<a href="/imsptools/index.php?r=SPPlite/default/retrieveWa1ir1s1service">wa1i-AFU R1S1</a>`  for this to use in selenium webdriver ?

Comment: Sorry the snippet got pasted twice. Please ignore the second repeated snippet

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to go for css instead since css is better in terms of performance.

```
a[href$='default/retrieveWa1ir1s1service']
```

Translation: Finds the anchor where href ends with *default/retrieveWa1ir1s1service*

Comment: Yes, I agree with Saifur. cssSelector is faster than xpath

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to read this post:

[XPath Tutorial](http://zvon.org/comp/r/tut-XPath_1.html)

It had solved many of my xpaths issues

Answer (score 0):

The possible xpath for this is: //a[text()='wa1i-AFU R1S1']

and the corresponding cssSelector/csspath is: a:contains(^wa1i-AFU R1S1$)

Sometimes, you can use absolute xpath which you can get by using Firebug and Firepath